# Why do we create?

Tags: idea

It could be an invention, or an idea, or anything.  What is the main reason behind why we create things?  I realize that there could be many reasons but I'm wondering if they can be summed up into one main reason.

Comment: Good question, who downvoted?

Comment: @GeorgeChen I wasn't sure if this was the right place for a question like this but I threw it out there anyway.

Comment: Is there any chance you could draw this out a little more? What exactly is it you would like someone here to explain to you? What might have made this an important problem for you in your study of philosophy? (Is there anything in particular you've been reading or studying that's made this problem become interesting to you?)

Answer (score 2):

That answer depends heavily on the philosophy you are using to approach it.  Some conflicting answers might be:

- Our concept of creation is illusionary, and it is the greater universe that is truly doing the creation.
- We create because God gave us the ability to do so.
- We create because it is the most powerful method we have at our disposal for reducing our entropy.
- We create because it is required of us as humans by the supernatural forces that created the universe.
- We don't create.

I think you might be able to make an argument "we create because we are conscious, and creation makes it easier to think."

Answer (score 0):

The dominant reason behind creativity is blind impulse. Few communities have realized the value of blind impulses because blind impulses do not appear to have purposes. In Bertrand Russell's words:

> In all men who have any vigorous life, there are strong impulses such as may seem utterly unreasonable to others. Blind impulses sometimes lead to destruction and death, but at other times they lead to the best things the world contains. Blind impulse is the source of war, but it is also the source of science, and art, and love. It is not the weakening of impulse that is to be desired, but the direction of impulse towards life and growth, rather than towards death and decay.
>
> Source: Russell, Bertrand. [Why Men Fight](https://archive.org/stream/whymenfightmetho00russuoft#page/6/mode/2up/search/%22All+human+activity+springs+from+two+sources%3A%22). New York: The Century Co. 1917

Since events in the brains do not transcend physical laws, the ultimate reason why some people have these impulses must lie in the physical nature of these brains. In another book, *Education and the Good Life*, Russell emphasized the importance of good habits.